# F# await Task and use its result

Tags: .net, .net-core, f#

I'm a bit new to F#, I'm trying to use some C# classes inside F# module.

```
let getApps (context: MyContext) =
    context.Provider.GetService<AppRepository>().GetActiveAsync().Result
    |> List.ofSeq
    |> List.map printName
    |> ignore
```

C# developer in me screams: `.Result` is bad . So my question is, how to refactor this code into a more elegant way and also take advantage of proper async programming in F#.

I've been trying to use different variations of:

```
|> Async.AwaitTask
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

But it looks ugly and not short, not to say I'm not sure if it uses processor time efficiently.

Comment: isn't this just `let! getApps (context: MyContext) =
    context.Provider.GetService<AppRepository>()`  ? (with `with open FSharp.Control.Tasks`) - related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/asynchronous-and-concurrent-programming/async

Comment: @Andrei what type is context.Provider.GetService<AppRepository>()?  and what type is GetActiveAsync?

Comment: @KoenigLear GetActiveAsync is of type `Task<List<App>>`. `GetService<AppRepository>()` is of type `AppRepository`. These are all C# classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should do the trick:

```
let getApps (context: MyContext) =
    async{
       let! result = context.Provider.GetService<AppRepository>().GetActiveAsync() 
                     |> Async.AwaitTask

       result
       |> Seq.iter printName
    }

getApps ctx
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This way you're not blocking the thread while waiting for GetActive to finish.   On a side note if you are executing something you can use Seq.iter instead of Seq.map and you don't need to convert to a list. You can work with a seq.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm having some troubles here https://prnt.sc/t110op. Would you able to point me at my mistakes?

Comment: @Andrei indentation issues! just push everything below getApps a tab.  I edited the sample above to highlight it.

Comment: Ok awesome! Appreciate your help!  VSCode tools aren't great. Do you have any suggestions on what to use on Mac?

Comment: @Andrei indentation errors are pain regardless of editor even in VS in Windows.  You get used to them and can spot them more easily.   I also have a Mac and VSCode with Ionide extensions is probably the best.  You can try Visual Studio for Mac but it's a bit on the slow side.

Comment: Yea, tried. Don't like it, will stick with VSCode. Maybe I'd be ok if I'd do all-F#, but most of my stuff is C# and F# is just a small project, C# class that called the F# method still says, method doesn't exist sigh. All good will figure it out as I go. Thank you again!

Answer (score 5):

One thing to keep in mind is that `Async.RunSynchronously` is basically the same thing as accessing `Result`. Both of these operations block the current thread, wait until the background operation completes and then give you the result.

This means that there is no point in using `async { .. }` if you will need to wait for the result using `RunSynchronously`. (Aside from the fact that `RunSynchronously` has a very long and ugly name that explicitly and clearly tells you that this is what's going on!)

If you can structure your code so that you do not need to wait, then it's worth changing `getApps` so that it returns the result asynchronously:

```
let getApps (context: MyContext) = async {        
  let! repos = 
    context.Provider.GetService<AppRepository>().GetActiveAsync()
    |> Async.AwaitTask
  return repos |> List.map printName }
```

You can then call this from another `async { .. }` block and eventually, start a computation in the background using `Async.Start`. However, there is no point in doing this if you'll use `Async.RunSynchronously`.

Comment: a bit disappointed that F# doesn't provide shorter syntax to work with tasks. Makes it hard for me to justify using it on enterprise projects with everything there being async. Thanks for your answer anyways!

Comment: @Andrei TaskBuilder.fs has been very helpful for me in this regard (https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskBuilder.fs)